# Understand what the assemble code for <getbuf> does

Tags: assembly, buffer, overflow

Questions 1:
I am reading about buffer overflow attacks and saw some examples, however I am having issues grasping what's going on the assemble code level. Can someone please help me understand this assemble code?

Questions 2:
In this attack we did a 24 padding bits then the destination address, which address here gets overwritten by the new destination address.

Questions 3:
I know the first column is for address, but I am confused what's the second column for example in the 1st line we have  1 48 38 ec

Dummy code:

```
<getbuf>
4019a1   48 38 ec     sub $0x18, rsp    // 24 bit for buffer? but what's rsp?
4019a8   48 38 ec 18  mov %rsp, %rdi    // rdi == arg, but what's rsp?
4019ac   48 89 e7     call <gets>       // not sure what does <gets> do
4019af   e8 8c 02 00  add  $0x18, %rsp  // not sure what's going on.
4019b4   48 83 c4 18  retq              // return?
4019be   c3           xchg %ax %ax      // I thought we returned already
```

this is not the actual code, but just a close representation.

Comment: You need to try again. The code you posted is completely messed up, opcodes do not correspond to the assembly mnemonics etc. (and it's 24 bytes, not bits)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can someone please help me understand this assemble code?
>
> 24 bit for buffer? but what's rsp?

`rsp` is the stack pointer. Stack is some area in the memory used for temporary data storage by functions. On many CPUs (including x86), the `call` instruction also stores the address of the instruction which shall be executed after the `ret` or `retq` instruction to the stack.

On x86 CPUs, the `rsp` (32-bit: `esp`) register contains an address. The memory before that address is free, the memory at that address and after that address is used.

If you need 100 bytes of temporary memory, you subtract 100 from the `rsp` register; doing so, you indicate that these 100 bytes of memory are used (by your code). As soon as you don't need the memory any longer, you restore the old value of `rsp`.

Because `retq` assumes that `rsp` points to the memory where `call` stored the address, you have to  restore the old value of `rsp` before you execute `retq`.

> not sure what does `gets` do

`gets` is a function intended for C programming. It reads in one line of text (e.g. from the keyboard). In your case, the line is written to the stack. Unlike `fgets` this function will **not** check if there is enough space in the memory!

If the line read is longer than 24 bytes, the `gets` function will overwrite the data in the memory that was "used" before the `sub $0x18, %rsp` instruction.

And as I already wrote, the address written by `call` and read by `retq` is stored there!

In other words: If the line read in by `gets` is too long, the address written by `call` is overwritten and the `retq` instruction will not return to the calling function but it will jump to some wrong address in the memory.

(I hope this answers Question 2.)

> I thought we returned already

The `xchg %ax %ax` is not really an instruction here, but simply some dummy data. It is inserted by some compilers because these compilers always generate functions that are a multiple of (for example) two bytes long.

> but I am confused what's the second column for example in the 1st line we have 1 48 38 ec

This is the bytes (in hexa-decimal notation) in RAM that represent the assembler instructions in the 3rd column.

Example: The hexa-decimal bytes `48 38 ec` in RAM will be interpreted as `sub $0x18, %rsp` by the CPU.

(Please also note tum_'s comment: The data shown in your example is obviously wrong: `48 38 ec` is obviously not the bytes representing the instruction `sub $0x18, %rsp`.)

Comment: @Akiji_nIKmOK  The `xchg %ax,%ax` (note the missing comma) is 66 90. The `48 38 ec` is invalid, `sub $0x18, %rsp` is `48 83 ec 18`. The addresses in the first column don't make much sense either... I did not downvote only because it's your first post, but please have some respect to people who you ask for help.